# Parsing xml using Ling in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi I have an Xml document, read from file using

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

The xml looks like this,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM 'xmlschemas/some.dtd'>
<document xmlns='http://www.abcd.com/dxl' version='9.0' someversion='1.0' 
          replicaid='0xxxxDB' form='Test'>
   <item name='From'>
      <text>John Doe</text>
   </item>
   <item name='SentTo'>
      <text>Another John Doe</text>
   </item>
   <item name='ModTime'>
      <datetime dst='true'>20180129T114649,22-02</datetime>
   </item>
   <item name='Body' sign='true' seal='true'>
       <attachmentref name='some.pdf' displayname='some.pdf'>
           <picture height='34px' width='342px'>
                <notesbitmap>
                    lQAmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAFYBI
                </notesbitmap>
           </picture>
```

How do I parse such an xml using Linq while targeting 'item' tags having specific name attributes?
Tried this with no success.,

```
 doc.Descendants("document")
 .Where(item =>
 {
    string cus = (string)item.Element("item");
    return cus != null && cus == "name";
 })
 .Descendants("SentTo")
 .Select(d => d.Value)
 .ToList();
```

I want to target item tags with name attributes 'From' and 'SentTo', there are other tags which I may not want to target.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: XPath will do what you need.  You can target elements by type and by attribute easily with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath select elements with specific attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841537/xpath-select-elements-with-specific-attribute-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're looking for elements without a namespace, but your document *does* specify a default namespace. Fortunately, LINQ to XML makes namespace handling easy.

You're also using `Descendants` to try to find the value of an attribute (I believe) which isn't how that works.

Here's an example that *does* work - assuming that your aim was to get the `<text>` content from each `<item>` element with a `name` attribute of `SentTo`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.abcd.com/dxl";
        var sentToValues = doc.Root
            .Elements(ns + "item")
            .Where(item => (string) item.Attribute("name") == "SentTo")
            .Select(item => (string) item.Element(ns + "text"))
            .ToList();
        foreach (var value in sentToValues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to target multiple tags in a single Linq query, like From, SentTo and SentDate etc all simultaneously?

Comment: @MichaelPhilips: Those aren't "tags" (elements) - they're attribute values. You could certainly have `Where(item => interestingNames.Contains((string) item.Attribute("name"))` where `interestingNames` is a list or set of From, SentTo and SentDate, for example. Alternatively, you could parse all items into a Name/Value dictionary, or something similar. There are lots of different approaches here.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to use HtmlAgilityPack for XML parsing. However, if you see why it might be a problem, but then still accept this decision, then you can do something like:

```
var relevantItems = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("item")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Item = x,
        ItemName = x.Attributes.Contains("name") ? x.Attributes["name"].Value : null
    })
    .Where(x => x.ItemName == "From" || x.ItemName == "SentTo")
    .Select(x => x.Item)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Has the question changed? I don't see anything about the HtmlAgilityPack here. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your xml contains `namespace`. So you have to read that namespace too in your code

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

var text = doc.Descendants(ns + "item")
              .Single(c => c.Attribute("name").Value == "SentTo")
              .Elements(ns + "text")
              .Select(item => (string)item)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Output:**

[image]

So, if you want to take more than one `name` attribute `text` node then

```
//This is sample string of array
string[] strArray = new string[2] { "From", "SentTo" };

var list = doc.Descendants(ns + "item")
              .Where(c => strArray == null || strArray.Any(x => x.Contains(c.Attribute("name").Value)))
              .Elements(ns + "text")
              .Select(item => (string)item)
              .ToList();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make class Item with properties and attributes that I need and deserialize XML into it, later on, I would use LINQ to filter values. Take a look here:

[How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

http://www.janholinka.net/Blog/Article/11

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a comment really, not an answer.

Comment: I don't have reputation for comments :(

Comment: Then go get some, it's easy to get up to 50 with only edit suggestions :)